Cloud Build can't find config file in public GitHub repo
I am trying to build the Terraform cloud builder. Following the example in the gcloud builds submit doc, I run:
gcloud builds submit https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community \
  --region="$REGION" \
  --git-source-revision=master \
  --git-source-dir=terraform \
  --config=cloudbuild.yaml

but it gives me an error
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) Unable to read file [cloudbuild.yaml]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cloudbuild.yaml'

The cloudbuild.yaml file is not in the repo root directory, but I would expect that --git-source-dir would tell it where to look.  Anyway, even if I specify --config=terraform/cloudbuild.yaml, it gives me the same error.
I know I can clone the repo myself and run the build from my local directory, but from the documentation it seems like these options should do what I want.  Am I missing something, or does it just not work?

consider running the command with the --verbosity=debug flag to get more detailed output and have a look at this link and doc

I suspect that gcloud build submit is looking for cloudbuild.yaml in the working directory before cloning the repo. I think the way to do this is to (shallow) clone the repo first, cd ${REPO}/terraform and then run gcloud builds submit ${PWD}.

@DazWilkin Yes, I know that works, but this seems like such an obvious use case (and the doc suggests it is supported) that I wondered if I was doing something wrong.

I have tried the same command I’m also getting the same error even with the --config=terraform/cloudbuild.yaml
Have a look at below note mentioned in document

Directory, relative to the source root, in which to run the build. This must be a relative path. If a step's dir is specified and is an absolute path, this value is ignored for that step's execution.

Hence, maybe you have to make sure it didn’t set a different directory.
If the issue still persists after the directory check, I think you should report the issue at the public bug tracker in GCP. To do so, You can raise a public issue tracker with your use case details and you may track the progress over there.

The cloudbuild.yaml file exists in the specified directory.  I submitted an issue to Google.

@JohnVelonis What should I do when someone answers my question?
